# Authentication Failed for URL after asking credentials from Microsoft

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops and in the website I can access to the files and create a new branch also.

However, when I move to command line in my company computer, I received

> fatal: Authentication failed for "https://{Org}@dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_git/{Project}/"

for all git command including fetch, push, pull. Everytime a dialog from Microsoft popped up to ask me to login.

[dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UReWh.png)

[dialog image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK5Ec.png)

This is my cmd line to add remote:

```
> git init 
> git remote add origin https://{Org}@dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_git/{Project}/
> git fetch
```

This is my cmd line config result:

```
> git config --list --local
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://{Org}@dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_git/{Project}/
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I don't know if the below information is useful:

1. We have more than one directory in Azure Devops
2. In user setting, I found so many same Personal Access Tokens on the same date of next year.

[Tokens image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA04v.png)

Please help!

Comment: Hi @Kwan. Is there any update about this ticket? Could you please check if it could work when you add the PAT in the Git URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fatal: Authentication failed for xxx

You could navigate to `Control Panel --> Credential Manager --> Manage Windows Credentials` on your local machine.

Then you couldcheck whether there are certificates related to organization.

For example:

```
git:https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx
```

You could [create a new PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) in azure devops. Then you could edit the certificates and set the PAT as the password of the certificates.

If it doesn't work, you could remove existing certificates. Then you could re-run the same command and create new certificate on local machine.

On the other hand, you could also try to add the PAT in the Git URL.

For example:

```
git remote add origin https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_git/{RepoName}
```

By the way, from the Token image, these tokens are automatically generated when you run the git command.

Comment: Do {PAT} means the long token or the name of token?

Comment: @Kwan. The content of the token instead of the name of the token. in other words, long token.

Comment: It is not work for me/.\ The exact certificate related to organization is in credential manager. Also, even I change content of token as the password, it still appears a dialog to ask me to login. I am not sure if setting pwd is useful.

Comment: Could you please try to remove all existing certificates and run the same command again? In this case, you still need to log in for the first time. You could try to add the PAT in the Git URL. Based on my test, this method could skip the login step. To check if it could work, you could check if you could fetch the files successfully.